# Git as document Manager tool

Tags: sharepoint, gitlab, document-management

My enterprise would like to move from a paid, complicated and partially fulfilling tool to GitLab as our document management tool.
Our requirements are 
1.  We should be able to track the document history. 
2.  If a user is editing a document, it should be locked for other users for editing.
3.  The changes made by the user must be merged with the previous versions
4.  We must be able to share the specific version of the document to the internal and external users in a repository.
Please help me decide if GIT is the right option for the document management keeping the above requirements in mind. If you have worked with sharepoint, can yu share your view on using it as a document manager. I have used git for storing my codes and for project works before. We are currently using the git repository in my company for saving our development work.

Comment: What have you decided? And have you evaluated the document review capabilities? (I think on GitLab, comments can be added per line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. We should be able to track the document history.

Yes (core)

> 2. If a user is editing a document, it should be locked

No. Git does not support lock-model

> 3. The changes made by the user must be merged with the previous versions

Yes (core)

> 4. We must be able to share the specific version of the document

No, AFAICR - you have only repository-URL as entity, not (any) object inside it